# My StackOverflow is 100% orange

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching, design

I usually go between main index and interesting tag pages. With recent homepage changes all pages are now orange for me anywhere I usually go.

I like the idea to mark interesting tags (and new homepage), but maybe orange background is too strong for interesting tags.

The fact that interesting tag pages are 100% orange was always bugging me, but now with orange main index I thought it might be a time to suggest rethink the idea with orange backgrounds to make them less intrusive.

Comment: But is it from concentrate?

Comment: My StackOverflow is 100% apple! (not really)

Comment: -1. Stack Overflow contains less than 10% actual fruit juice. Read the faq.

Comment: @KennyTM: Are you maybe hitting the wrong site?  http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: are you still having this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I think the solution is to quit considering EVERYTHING interesting. We get it, we're programmers. We like interesting things too. We are fascinated by shiny new things and challenging problems.

I have six tags interesting on SO, and with the new homepage it's mostly orange. But when I revert it's mostly white.

Also, it's a rather lovely christmassy layout if you consider the color of highlight golden instead. Then I have gold, green and red.