# Site elements display weirdly in Firefox nightly build

Tags: support, user-interface, firefox

I am using a Firefox nightly build and I am not able see all questions correctly. Some rows are displaying in yellow and some are in white. When I try to answer, the editor is not displaying correctly; all the editor controls are collapsed. The site works well on IE.

[image: Screen shot of Error]

Comment: The broken editor is probably due to Firefox nightly being unsupported, and some incompatibility there.  The fact that you're reporting a bug from a nightly build here is probably why you're being downvoted.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this question belongs on Superuser or Stackoverflow, but it doesn't appear to be relevant to Meta Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not an error. Questions with your favorite tags will have a yellow background.

I think there's even some automatic detection of your most active tags and those get auto-favorited (don't quote me on that).

Comment: There is automatic detection, you can quote me on that.  Lemme go get a reference on how it works..

Comment: OK, they're called "Frequented tags" and are used only if you've not set any [Favorite tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-favorite-tags-and-ignored-tags-do).  You can opt out by [setting an unused favorite tag like `sdfcy8rt972d`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88345/please-let-users-opt-out-of-the-frequented-tag-system).

Comment: There is more confusion [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96389/why-are-etymology-questions-on-german-sx-highlighted-for-me), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96389/why-are-etymology-questions-on-german-sx-highlighted-for-me), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11253/under-questions-why-are-some-with-a-yellow-background), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72587/why-is-stack-overflow-suddenly-orange) [and here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69984/my-stackoverflow-is-100-orange).  Feel free to incorporate any of this in your answer.